# What value should I return in case of error if I want to declare a function type in PHP?

Tags: php, types

I am working on a PHP project and maintaining a ten years old application.
In this project, no one has ever used type declarations, but it looks like a good practice to me and I try (as often as possible) to write clean code.
As a junior developer, it is not always easy when your manager does not care about good practices ^^.

I am writing a function which is supposed to return an object.

```
/**
 * Returns a coefficient object depending on the pack size given as an argument
 * @param int|null $pack_size
 * @return object
 */
function coefficient(int $pack_size = null) : object
{
    if (est_id($this->id))
    {
        // Checking that $pack_size is a number
        if (preg_match('`^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$`', $pack_size))
        {
            if (is_object($this->coefficient_group))
                $coefficient_resultSQL = coefficient::list(['group' => $this->coefficient_group->id(), 'size' => $pack_size]);
            if (!empty($coefficient_resultSQL->result))
            {
                $coefficient_src = reset($coefficient_resultSQL->result);
                $coefficient = new coefficient(null, ['element' => $coefficient_src]);
                
                if (!empty($coefficient) && est_id($coefficient->id()))
                    $result = $coefficient;
            }
        }
    }
    return (!empty($result)) ? $result : null;
}
```

The problem is that, by declaring the return type as an object, I cannot return 'null' if there is an error.
Then, what should I do if I wanted to return an explicit error value?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: While trying to go with  good practice is great, without a full refactoring of the code base you will end up making the software harder to maintain. Its a good idea when dealing with legacy code to stick to what ever practices have been defined.. good or not.

Comment: That's really a matter of opinion to some extent. A lot of people would say you should throw an exception rather than resorting to using specific values to represent error conditions. But then again if your application follows a consistent approach similar to the `null` return shown above, then it might not be a good idea to disrupt it, in terms of code maintainability etc. "good practice" is also a matter of opinion. Type checking can be useful, but then again PHP was designed loosely-typed, and sometimes that's useful.

Comment: What version of PHP?

Comment: We are currently using PHP 7.3

Comment: @DevWithZachary
It's a really interesting answer.
I find it really difficult to find the right balance between stricking to the existing code base and trying to make it more "modern" and clean.
I often try to reproduce what was done before, in order to maintain a certain harmony, but sometimes I think that if everybody does the same thing, the code base will never be improved.

Comment: I wonder what the callers will do with this null value, except propagate an error one level down the call chain. There are at least 4 possible causes for invalid results. Better call a panic function right there and force the caller(s) to correct their code than silently produce an unusable value, if you ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP 7, `Type declarations for parameters and return values can now be marked as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark.`

e.g. `function coefficient(int $pack_size = null) : ?object`

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php

Comment: Thanks, now I know that I need to improve my google search skills :)